# Sum of two n bit numbers (n<=255) in 8085 microprocessor

Tags: microprocessors, 8085

```
LDA 2000h ; Store the no of byte that each number consists of in memory location 2000h.
MOV C A
MOV B A
LXI D 5000h
LXI H 2001h
STC
CMC
LOOP1: MOV A M
SHLD 7000h
LOOP: INX H
DCR C
JNZ LOOP
ADC M
STAX D
LHLD 7000h
LDA 2000h
MOV C A
INX D
INX H
DCR B
JNZ LOOP1
HLT
```

This is my code for the above mentioned problem. What would be more efficient algorithm to do so?

Comment: I guess you work in a museum. But format the question a bit better

Comment: @EdHeal He come here to get help

Comment: It was a joke. But the question could do with being formatted better

Comment: What do mean by  working in a museum and what kind of formatting do you want?? @Ed Heal

Comment: The formatting is a lot better after the edit. The 8085 processor is a cira. 1970 and 8 bit

Comment: I can't get you. Is there any solution of my problem?